# GraphQL using a for loop in within the search query

Tags: python, graphql, yelp-fusion-api

Because Yelp limits the output of businesses to 50, I'm trying to loop through the Census block centroid longitudes and latitudes of San Diego to get all the different businesses (which I want for a project). However, the query does not seem to accept anything that is not strictly numeric. Am I missing something?

This is the error:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport

yelp_api_key = 'xxx'

#define headers
header = {'Authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(yelp_api_key),
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

#url = "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=san%2520diego&sort_by=best_match&limit=20"



append_data = []
for i in range(0,len(bcx)):
    #PARAMETERS = {'limit': 50, 
    #              'offset': 0,
     #             'longitude': bcx[i],
      #            'latitude': bcy[i]
       #          }
    
    #build request framework
    transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/graphql', headers = header, use_json = True) #params = PARAMETERS

# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
    client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)
    
    # Provide a GraphQL query
    query_bus = gql("""
    {
    sd_businesses: search(location: "san diego", limit: 50, 
                  offset: 0,
                  longitude: bcx[i],
                  latitude: bcy[i]){
        total
        business {
            name
            coordinates{
            latitude
            longitude  
            }
            }
        }
    }
    """)




    # Execute the query on the transport
    result_bus = client.execute(query_bus)
    append_data.append(result_bus)

    
print(append_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to do python variable substitution inside the GraphQL query string and the GraphQL interpreter can't deal with that. You need to use [variables](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/variables.html) to define the parameters of your query.

```
params = {
  "location": "san diego",
  "limit": 50,
  "offset": 0,
  "longitude": bcx[i],
  "latitude": bcy[i]
}

query_bus = gql("""
  query sd_businesses($location: String, $limit: Number, $offset: Int, $longitude: Float, $latitude: Float) {
    search(location: $location, limit: $limit, offset: $offset, longitude: $longitude, latitude: $latitude) {
      total
      business {
        name
        coordinates {
          latitude
          longitude  
        }
      }
    }
  }
""")

# Execute the query on the transport
result = client.execute(query, variable_values=params)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I've looked over variables in defining parameters but never understood how or why I would want to use them until reading your answer! I think there is an extra "{" on the "search" line. If I change that, I'm getting the error ```Unknown type 'Number'. Did you mean 'User'?``` I've looked at a couple posts (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204685/graphql-query-erroring-with-unknown-type-int-with-apollo-client-and-graphql-go) but am not sure the cause.

Comment: I actually figured this out by changing "Number" to either "Int" or "Float". Thanks so much for your help!